# C# console, How to reach the identified variable from one class to another class?

Tags: c#, class, interface, console

```
    interface ICar
    {
        int Speed {get; set;}
    }
    class IgnitionKey: ICar
    {
        public int Speed {get; set;}
        public void Change () 
        {
            Speed = 10;
        }
    }

    class GasBrake: IgnitionKey
    {

    }
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        IgnitionKey k = new IgnitionKey();
        GasBrake s = new GasBrake();
        k.Change();
        Console.WriteLine(s.Speed);
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
```

Here is my code. Using Change function, I change speed value to 10. But this speed value belongs to interface (I guess). I have a second class that inherits from other class. I want Speed value to be equal to ten.

In main, if I use Console.WriteLine(k.Speed) I can get value 10. But I need to get this value when I use s.Speed. How can I do that ? Is there a way to change the value of first class using second class ?

(Sory for bad English)

Answer (score 0):

In your code, `k` and `s` refer do different objects, so changes in one of them cannot affect the other.
You can write `GasBrake s = k;` to make booth variables refer to the same object, or you may call `s.Change()` instead of `k.Change()` to modify `s`

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I have one more question.                     public void Change () 
        {    GasBreak g = new GasBreak();
            g.Speed = 10;
        }                                                                                                      I write this code in IgnitionKey class then I run this function in main. After that, Consol.WriteLine g.Speed  but this time both g.Speed and s.Speed  is equal to zero. I thougth g.Speed would be equal to 10. Why not ?

Comment: You really, really need to read a book about the fundamentals of C# and object oriented programming. In short, your variable g is disposed of as soon as your `Change` method is done.

Comment: GasBreak g = new GasBreak(); g.Speed = 10;     if I write this code in main, it works. But I use  it in IgnitionKey class with a function and I use that function in main. And this doesn't work. I really don't get it

Answer (score 0):

When you do :

```
 GasBrake s = new GasBrake();
```

or:

```
IgnitionKey k = new IgnitionKey();
```

that is a new object created and it has it's own allocated memory and it's own state which is completely isolated from the other and they don't have any shared state.

As you have two completely different objects being created they both will have completely different state, they cannot share state. For mimicking what you want you will need to use single object but with different type of reference :

```
GasBrake s = new GasBrake(); // now just one object created
IgnitionKey k = s;  // we reference to it using the parent class type 
k.Change();  // change it's value

    Console.WriteLine(s.Speed); // same value will be printed
```

now you will see same value i.e. **10**.

Comment: Thank you I get it but all this code will be written in main right ? I want the main code to be as less as possible. Can we use this code in one of the classes with a function and after that use that function in main ?